# Is it possible to let the table split into more columns according to its container's width?

Tags: html, css

I have a very long table (more than 100 rows).

When the container is wide (on a big external monitor), I hope it will take advantage of the wide space as follows:

[image]

When the container is narrow (on a mobile), I hope it just looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible with HTML and CSS?

Comment: Is the tabular data you're presenting only 3 columns wide? If so then you could just have multiple tables and [float them like so](https://jsfiddle.net/7vykrbxj/). Simple solution potentially. This question is a bit broad though and you haven't shown any attempts you've made.

Comment: Some are of 2 columns and some are of 3. But no more than 3. I have checked your solution, if I have to split one `<table>` into three `<table>`s, it requires some scripts to do some preparation job and it seems I need to worry about how many rows are there. I think this is a somehow common situation because a thin and long table on a desktop screen wastes too much horizontal space.

Comment: Another solution is to leave it to the user.  Provide `+` and `-` buttons that refresh the page.

Comment: Are you able to alter the HTML?

Comment: @RohitGupta Any example? I don't quite catch with the + and - tricks. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can alter the HTML from a table to simple divs you could set it as a grid with break points for different viewport widths.

We need four (or how ever many the maximum you require is) copies of the column headings built in to the HTML.

This snippet has 4 breakpoints and obviously you'll want to put in the values you actually need.

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.table :nth-child(4),
.table :nth-child(5),
.table :nth-child(6),
.table :nth-child(7),
.table :nth-child(8),
.table :nth-child(9),
.table :nth-child(10),
.table :nth-child(11),
.table :nth-child(12) {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  }
  .table :nth-child(4),
  .table :nth-child(5),
  .table :nth-child(6) {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  }
  .table :nth-child(7),
  .table :nth-child(8),
  .table :nth-child(9) {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .table {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  }
  .table :nth-child(10),
  .table :nth-child(11),
  .table :nth-child(12) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<div class="table">
  <div>item</div>
  <div>Value A</div>
  <div>Value B</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>Value A</div>
  <div>Value B</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>Value A</div>
  <div>Value B</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>Value A</div>
  <div>Value B</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>iii</div>
  <div>aaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this inspirational answer. Though I can't alter table to div because I want to keep the semantic structure and that is also the reason I can't split one table into more tables. Maybe there is nothing I can do with pure CSS.

Comment: I can’t see how to keep a single table using only CSS. Apart from anything else you need several copies of the th elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to handle **table** in a responsive way.  I normally target mine to the smallest size.

Since you want to keep the **semantic structure** and still **split the table**, I think you need to do this manually.

I suggest that you provide 2 or 3 **different formats** of the table and let the **user select one**.  Maybe provide two buttons <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>.  Or provide a dropdown to select a format/size.